# GAE php "urlfetch error"

Tags: php, google-app-engine

i want to get a webpage content via my gae php application.
but the code doesn't work.

my code is:

```
echo file_get_contents("http://www.navyfield.com", false);
```

and i tried my code on php-minishell,http://php-minishell.appspot.com/
it didnt work either.

here is the result

```
Google App Engine/1.8.7
PHP 5.4.19
>>> file_get_contents("http://www.navyfield.com", false);
file_get_contents(http://www.navyfield.com): failed to open stream: Fetch error
```

anyone got idea about this?

Comment: PHP minishell doesn't give a very elaborate error report, probably for security reasons. Can  you copy the error message from the dev server logs?

Comment: Had a quick look, nothing obviously wrong. Could you site be blocking the ip addresses that app engine is using to access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done some checking it looks like that site is blocking the connection. I tried with URL fetch and with a raw socket from our IP range.